# Turn off 2-factor authentication without device

Tags: asp.net-core, recovery, two-factor-authentication

I've implemented 2-factor authentication in my ASP.NET Core application. Yesterday I implemented the use of recovery codes, to be used in case a user loses his device.

My question is actually pure theoretical.

If a user has used a recovery code, we don't want to disable the 2-factor authentication. But in order to disable 2FA, the user needs to generate a verification code using his mobile phone. So he will not be able to turn off 2FA in any way.

So the only thing to do for someone who has lost his device is to keep using backup codes, keep an eye that they don't run out, and generate new backup codes in time (which he has to write down again). Or ask the administrator to disable 2FA for him. But isn't there a better way to deal with this kind of cases?

[image: 2FA recovery using ASP.NET Core]

Comment: So if the user loses their phone/changes phone numbers, they will have to use a recovery code every time in the future when they log in? It doesn't sound like a great UX to me.. Pretty sure that typically the recovery codes act as a 2FA bypass and then you can disable 2FA/re-register 2FA from the settings.

Comment: Indeed that's what I'm wondering. However I see now that with ASP.NET Core Identity, you do NOT need a verification code to disable 2FA (little wrong assumption from my part). So should you put a checkbox below with "Turn off two-factor authentication"? And when the recovery code is valid turn it off? Is that a good idea or a dangerous thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

- Enable 2-factor authentication: Obviously, here you request a verificationcode
- During login: Request verificationcode, but also allow `TwoFactorRecoveryCodeSignInAsync`

[image: Login 2-factor authentication]
[image: 2-factor Recovery]

- Disable 2-factor authentication: Allow both verificationcode and recoverycode

[image: Disable 2-factor authentication]

- Bypass 2-factor authentication for external logins + Generate new recoverycodes: Only allow verificationcode

[image]